# PHP: How to use file_get_contents even after sever ip is blocked

Tags: php, proxy, ip

I was using file_get_contents('http://www.somewebsite.com') function but my Server IP is blocked permanently. Is there any way that I can still access that website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. use CURL with anonimous proxies

```
$url = 'http://www.somewebsite.com';
$proxy = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```